# How to fix java.util.InputMismatchException for my scanner file reader?

Tags: java, arrays, file, java.util.scanner

I'm having some problems with my file reader that uses scanner, and I'm at a bit of a loss at this point. Trying to read the file with scanner but atm I keep getting a `java.util.InputMismatchException` message which suggests that my `scanner.next` is putting the wrong files in the wrong arrays? I don't know why this is happening, if someone could point out in my code where I'm screwing up, I'd appreciate it.

Note: Unless it is relevant, ignore the useless variables and the excessively long arrays. I was getting ready to make this into a class and some variables are not used yet.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
{
    int playersTotal = 0;
    int entries = 0;
    int namesIndex = 0;
    int attackIndex = 0;
    int blockIndex = 0;
    String[] playersName = new String[60];
    double[] attackScores = new double[60];
    double[] blockScores = new double[60];
    String file = "roster1.txt";
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File(file));
    scanner.useDelimiter(" ");

    while(scanner.hasNextLine())
    {
        playersName[namesIndex] = scanner.next();
        System.out.println(playersName[namesIndex]);
        namesIndex ++;
        playersName[namesIndex] = scanner.next();
        System.out.println(playersName[namesIndex]);
        namesIndex ++;
        entries ++;
        attackScores[attackIndex] = scanner.nextDouble();
        System.out.println(attackScores[attackIndex]);
        attackIndex ++;
        entries ++;
        //problem occurs here:
        blockScores[blockIndex] = scanner.nextDouble();
        System.out.println(blockScores[blockIndex]);
        blockIndex ++;
        entries ++;
        playersTotal ++;
    }
}
```

This should take every entry separated by a space from a list with both Strings and doubles on every line and save it to their proper arrays. However it only ever reaches the first double on the first line. Attempting to read the next double prompts an exception in thread.

Program output:

```
Rachael                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
Adams                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
3.36                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
        at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:864)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
        at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1485)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
        at java.util.Scanner.nextDouble(Scanner.java:2413)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
        at VerdeVolleyball.main(VerdeVolleyball.java:37)

list I'm using:
1. Rachael Adams 3.36 1.93
2. Kim Hill 1.53 1.76
3. Tori Dixon 0.92 1.62
4. Alisha Glass 1.96 1.55
5. Cursty Jackson 0.69 1.44
6. Michelle Bartsch 0.28 1.42
7. Alexis Crimes 3.89 1.34
8. Foluke Akinradewo 4.81 1.14
9. Courtney Thompson 0.59 0.93
10. Krista Vansant 2.78 0.86
11. Nicole Fawcett 4.01 0.61
12. Kelly Murphy 1.15 0.58
13. Natalie Hagglund 2.49 0.52
14. Kayla Banwarth 2.98 0.5
15. Lauren Gibbemeyer 2.25 0.5
```

Comment: Can you share some sample input from the file you are reading?

Comment: Done, added the data of the list I'm using.

Comment: Off topic but why would you need more than one index variable for your arrays?

Comment: Honestly because I don't know a better way of doing it. I need to individually separate names and double values so I can print them in a format that is consistent of a team roster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to comment out the line where you specify the delimiter for Scanner instance
`scanner.useDelimiter(" ");`

and be sure that your Scanner instance uses proper locale when resolving double (`.` separator instead of `,`).

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File(file).useLocale(Locale.US);
```

Comment: That seems to have worked. It is recording all names and doubles to their corresponding arrays. I also had a problem with java.util.NoSuchElementException but is was easily solvable by removing "line" from scanner.hasnextline. Thank you for your help.